# Finding an iframe in TinyMCE textarea entered code

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Some people post the html of blog post that they want to share on our site.  However, iframes are not permitted on our site, so I want to check the entered code that none were entered into the TinyMCE editor.

I am running a validation javascript on submission and it has the following code:

```
 if (ErrorFound == 0)
 {
      if (tinyMCE.get("entryText").getContent().indexOf("<iframe") != -1)
      {
           alert("iframes are not accepted on this site as they can be used maliciously, please remove the offending code.");
           document.frmBlogEntry.entryText.focus();
           ErrorFound = ErrorFound + 1
      }
 }
```

What am i doing wrong? as when this is executed it is ignored.  It must be something obvious that I am missing.

Would really appreciate your help.
Many thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: Can you confirm that the getContent() method actually returns the HTML ? and where do you declare the ErrorFound variable ?

Comment: var ErrorFound is defined at the top of the script.. I just gave the part of the script that highlighted the issue..  The getContent() does return the html, yes..!

Comment: If you stick and `alert('here')` in at line 3 (ie first line after `if(errorfound)`) do you see the alert ?

Comment: Yes I do.. the alert fires no problem

Comment: Then i think this is the problem -> http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements the default set of allowable html elements doesnt include iframe - you would actually need to configure it to allow the iframe ....

Answer (score 2):

By default the TinyMCE Editor cleans the output from the editor .... this link shows the default list of elements allowed

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

the `iframe` tag is not on that list of valid elements (the default one) - i would suggest that its being removed by the editor itself ....

Comment: I solved it by assigning getContent() to a variable first and then checking the indexof, was just a javascript problem.. nothing related to tinymce.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by assigning getContent() to a variable first and then checking the indexof, was just a javascript problem.. nothing related to tinymce. Many thanks